# Can't resolve Intendation error in python

Tags: python

I tried fixing up my indentation errors in python code. But was not able to resolve it. When tried fixing an error another indentation error pops up

I tried uploading the code on many online formators and tried resolving it, but was not successful

There was some error with the for loop formatting. After fixing it again throws another error

```
 if(date[0]>j):
    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I'm not able to find out the solution to it

```
for i in range(0,len(no2)):
    date=no2.Date[i].split('/')
    for k in range(0,len(date)):
        t=int(date[k])
        date[k]=t
    if(prev_month!=date[1]):
        sum=0.0
        print(type(sum))
        last_j=1
        prev_month=date[1]
    #print(year[0])
    #print(date[2])
    if(date[2]==year[0]):
        print(date[2])
        if(date[1]==1  or date[1]==3 or date[1]==5 or date[1]==7 or date[1]==8 or date[1]==10 or date[1]==12):
            #print(date[1])
            for j in range(last_j,31):
                print(date[0],j)
                if(date[0]==j):
                    #print(j)
                    new_date.append(no2.Date[i])
                    if no2.Concentration[i]=="":
                                                no2_data.append(sum/j-1)
                    else :
                                                no2_data.append(no2.Concentration[i])
                    sum=sum+float(no2_data[j-1])
                    last_j=j+1
                    break

                if(date[0]>j):
                    new_date.append(str(j)+"/"+str(date[1])+"/"+str(date[2]))
                    no2_data.append(sum/j-1)
                    sum=sum+float(no2_data[j-1])
                    last_j=j

        elif(date[1]==4  or date[1]==6 or date[1]==9 or date[1]==11):
            for j in range(last_j,30):
                print(date[0],j)
                if(date[0]==j):
                    #print(j)
                    new_date.append(no2.Date[i])
                    if no2.Concentration[i]=="":
                                                no2_data.append(sum/j-1)
                    else :
                                                no2_data.append(no2.Concentration[i])
                    sum=sum+float(no2_data[j-1])
                    last_j=j+1
                    break
                if(date[0]>j):
                    new_date.append(str(j)+"/"+str(date[1])+"/"+str(date[2]))
                    no2_data.append(sum/j-1)
                    sum=sum+float(no2_data[j-1])
                    last_j=j

        if(date[2]==2):
                for j in range(last_j,28):
                        if(date[0]==j):
                            new_date.append(no2.Date[i])
                            if(no2.Concentration[i]==""):
                                no2_data.append(sum/j-1)
                            else:
                                 no2_data.append(no2.Concentration[i])
                            sum=sum+float(no2_data[j-1])
                            last_j=j+1
                            break
                        if(date[0]>j):
                            new_date.append(str(j)+"/"+str(date[1])+"/"+str(date[2]))
                            no2_data.append(sum/j-1)
                            sum=sum+float(no2_data[j-1])
                            last_j=j


#print(new_date)
#print(no2_data)
df = pandas.DataFrame({"date" : new_date, "no2" : no2_data})
df.to_csv("/Users/hareini/Downloads/output.csv", index=False)
```

Please help me out with this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please be consistent with your tab/space indentation. In your question you can see that there are some extra spaces.

```
if(date[2]==2):
                for j in range(last_j,28):
                        if(date[0]==j):
                            new_date.append(no2.Date[i])
                            if(no2.Concentration[i]==""):
                                no2_data.append(sum/j-1)
                            else:
                                 no2_data.append(no2.Concentration[i])
                            sum=sum+float(no2_data[j-1])
                            last_j=j+1
                            break
                        if(date[0]>j):
                            new_date.append(str(j)+"/"+str(date[1])+"/"+str(date[2]))
                            no2_data.append(sum/j-1)
                            sum=sum+float(no2_data[j-1])
                            last_j=j
```

If you can't see the extra tabs in your editor, try to open your python file in IDLE and edit the tabs there.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) is some more information about indentation.